# keep selected value from dropdown after postback by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to Retain dropdownlist selected value after postback, I am trying hard to understand how to retain a dropdownlist selected value after postback.

on this function I get selected values from dropdownlist and  I save it in local storage:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        window.localStorage.setItem("Rooms", $("#Rooms option:selected").val());
        window.localStorage.setItem("Persons", $("#Persons option:selected").val());
        window.localStorage.setItem("Childrens", $("#Childrens option:selected").val());
    }
}
```

on page load I have `adddate()` function called:

```
function AddDate() {
    var date = moment();

    document.getElementById('Arrival').value = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    document.getElementById('Departure').value = date.add(1, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    $("#Arrival").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Arrival"));
    $("#Departure").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Departure"));
    $("#Rooms option:selected").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Rooms"));
    $("#Persons option:selected").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Persons"));
    $("#Childrens    option:selected").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Childrens"));
}; 
window.onload = AddDate;
```

below is my select list:

```
<select id="Rooms" name="Rooms" class="dropdown">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++){
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

I have tried with many options which did not work

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

Change the dropdown, and refresh the page.

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
      $("#Rooms").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Rooms"));
   });

   $("#Rooms").on('change',function(e){      
       window.localStorage.setItem("Rooms", $("#Rooms option:selected").val()); 
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/rpnoarof/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value on `#Rooms option:selected`, which will not work. Try `$("#Rooms").val(...)` instead.

Same goes for the selection before storing the value, although I guess your code works there as well.

Comment: I want to get selected value not only the value

Comment: The value of a `select` field, is the selected value. See: http://api.jquery.com/val/